# Visual Studio unit test detect failure

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

So I am writing tests in Visual Studio 2015, and executing using MS UnitTesting to run it. What I want to do is write some code then when the test it done I can update a rally test case. What I am looking for is how to detect if the test case that just ran passed or failed. I have been looking at reflection but not seeing an option for the test

```
[TestCleanup()]
public void MyTestCleanup()
{
    // Code to check if test passes or fails

    Common.DriverQuit();
}
```

Then based off that answer I can write the rest of the code. I just need to figure how to gain access to test results if possible.

Comment: You need Assert.....

Comment: No I am not saying how to pass or fail the test. I am talking about after the test is done I want to fine out if it passed or failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSTest framework has a `TestContext` class which holds all the information relating to the current test. You can access it by declaring a same-named property, which is then automatically set by the framework:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private TestContext testContextInstance;

    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get { return testContextInstance; }
        set { testContextInstance = value; }
    }

    ...
```

Having declared that, you can directly access the information you need:

```
[TestCleanup]
public void Cleanup()
{
    if (TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome == UnitTestOutcome.Failed)
    {
        // whatever...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the solution. What I was looking for was the TestContext.

```
TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome
```

This will give me a string of either pass or failed